# Always take all account online

Tags: mail.app

Occasionally, after reconnecting WiFi, `Mail.app`'s dock icon bounces, and a dialogue prompts if I want to take all of my mail accounts back online.

I can't imagine a single circumstance in which anyone would ever say "no". At the minimum, I always want to choose "yes".

Is there a way to make Mail just always automatically reconnect, unconditionally, without nagging me?

Comment: What is your OS version?

Comment: How often do you check for new messages? You can look it up in Mail > Preferences > General

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Oh I totally forgot to mention it. I'm on Mojave, 10.14.6.

Comment: @howdytom "Automatically" (does that mean push? I'm not sure)